# XE8 apps does not run in iOS 9.1?

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe8

I have an IOS app compiled in RAD Studio XE8 that no longer runs, and does not give an error message, after I updated the Xcode, MacOS and the iPad:

Xcode version 7.1
IOS Version: 9.1
MacOS version: 10.10.5

How can I make this app run in iOS 9.1 again?

Comment: According to this thread (https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=117612) you need to move to Seattle

Comment: I guess Seattle would have a big problem if everyone moved there.<g>